# react-hook-form V7: value is not cleared after unmounting its registered component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

In V6 when I toggled a component off, using the `watch` method, the component will be unmounted and so will any sibling that depends on the unmounted components' value:

For example:

- We have three components `<ComponentA />`, `<ComponentB />` and
  `<ComponentC />`.
- When `<ComponentA />` equals 'Yes', `<ComponentB/>` is rendered.
- When `<ComponetB />` equals 1 or 2, `<ComponentC />`is rendered.
- Finally, if I change `<ComponentA />` to 'No' `<ComponentB />` and `<ComponentC />` will be unmounted and their values will be cleared.

Working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-rfhv6-001-xy39c

On the other hand, **in V7** when I change `<ComponentA />` to 'No', `<ComponentB />` is unmounted but its value is not cleared. Therefore,`<ComponentC />` is not unmounted.

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-rhfv7-001-rpg21

I have tried setting `shouldUnregister: true` as shown below but, still get the same behavior.

```
const { control, watch, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  mode: "all",
  shouldUnregister: true
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a breaking change from version 7. From the [migration guide](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/):

> **Important:** input value and reference will no longer get removed after unmount.

The solution is to detect when the component should be unmounted and call `unregister()` to clear the field manually:

```
const { ...props, unregister } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  if (watchRadio !== "Yes") {
    unregister("numOfSup");
  }
}, [watchRadio, unregister]);
```

You can see the issue about the subject [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3714). Search for *`shouldUnregister`* to see the relevant info.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67327916/react-hook-form-v7-key-value-in-fromstate-not-cleared-after-unmounting-its-regi]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @NearHuscarl

Also, I found a simpler way to fix the issue with the help of the one of react-hook-form creators. Upgrading its version.
In my case I was using version 7.0.5 and upgraded to 7.3.5.

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to detect when the component should be unmounted and call `unregister()` to clear the field manually.

FYI, for future reference, here is the working CSD:

### Live Demo 2

[image: Edit 67327916/react-hook-form-v7-key-value-in-fromstate-not-cleared-after-unmounting-its-regi]